# passport.js - Access fail message after 401 error

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, passport.js, http-status-code-401

Currently I can access messages set in `done(null, user, {message: 'ok'})` inside post request via `req.authInfo`like this:

```
app.post('/reg', passport.authenticate('local-reg', { session: false }), function (req, res) {        
        console.log(req.authInfo.message); --> 'ok'         
});
```

Which is very useful.
 But how can i access message like this `done(null, false, {message: 'username taken'})` in the same fashion, as it seems that passing `done(null, false)` in passport.authenticate makes it throw 401 unathorised, therefore not forwarding to the route handler itself.
Maybe i misunderstood something?

P.S.: I'm posting through `jQuery.post`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [custom callback](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/%20custom%20callback) where you have `info` accessible:

```
app.post('/req', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-reg', {session: false}, function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.json(info);
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.json(info);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

`req.authInfo` gets set only after successful login. If you were using sessions you could use flash messages with redirects, eg:

```
app.post('/reg', passport.authenticate('local-reg', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/',
  failureFlash: true,
  successFlash: true
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.flash());
});
```

Comment: I am using sessions, but it feels like overkill to connect whole flash messages module just to achieve such a simple task. I'll try a custom callback, it feels less workaround-ish and less code lines to change for me. I will check it out and then accept an answer (just want to hold it open for a bit in case if something goes wrong or if any other interesting answers will occure.).
Thank You for reply

Comment: So, this approach seems to work just fine.
As a side note, i understant that this is not the point in the answer, but isn't `req.logIn` is used to  deserialize user into session, therefore using it in example with `session:false` have no sense?
Thank You again)

Comment: I believe `req.logIn` also [sets `req.user`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/298d2452430dd0d1841d417e9c0d0b23e4b06239/lib/http/request.js#L29-L56). Deserializing is not done if `options.session` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has their own way of implementing it. In my implementation  if there are no errors and login is successful then :

`return done(null, {type : true, data: {email: <some email>, role : <some role>, name: <some name>}, token : <some token>});`

Whereas if any error or unsuccessful login then i do either

`return done(null, {type : false, data: 'Email is already taken.'});`

or

```
return done(null,{type:false, data: err})
```

So this makes my job simpler, i only check the `type` value and i can use it to pass values as well as error messages.

Comment: Yes, i thought about this way, but in fact it's a workaround i.e using succesfull done for both success and fail cases. It will work in my case. But i'm curious, why there is a possibility to pass message in third argument if it's ain't gonna be passed anywhere in case of fail. And the fail case is pretty much a case where this messages required most of all.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, yet i decided to go with custom callback idea below, as it simply means less code rewrite for me, but it was intresting to see that someone implements it this way also.

Comment: thanks man, that it helped you, let me know if you find better way in implementing same.