# passportjs - how to access status message in case of 401

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm using the local strategy of passportjs:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(username, password, done) {
    if (username === "myuser" && password === "mypass")
        return done(null, { name: "myuser" });

    return done(null, false, { data: 'Incorrect username and/or password' });
}));
```

In the case of a 401 status, I would like the client to get my status message: 'Incorrect username and/or password'. Instead, all I see in the body of the response is the word 'Unauthorized'. How can I access the message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object you are passing as the third parameter using `req.authInfo` . Then you can retrieve `data` from it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this: When I accept the POST request:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.authInfo);
    res.send(req.user);
});
```

The console.log(req.authInfo) doesn't get called in case of a 401 status, only in case of a 200. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

See the response of this post: [passport.js - Access fail message after 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662886/passport-js-access-fail-message-after-401-error)

You have to put your passport.authenticate in the function response:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, response) { 
       if(!response.success) {
          res.status(401).json({ 
            message: 'Incorrect username and/or password'
          });
       }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Obviously you have also to put in your local strategy the third param to

```
if(InvalidPassword or user not exist) {
  return next(null, false, { success: false });
}
```